# Arrows with tikz between words in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikzmark

I would like, ideally, to reproduce the following picture.
[image]

I am using the tikz package at the moment and my code is as follows (all packages and the frame I would like to modify):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,braket,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{At the intersection between Machine Learning and
Econometrics: theory and applications}
\subtitle{}
% \date{\today}
\date{}
\author{Federico Nutarelli}
\institute{IMT School for Advanced Studies, Lucca}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Logo.png}
}
% \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.pdf}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%%%%%% HERE IS THE FRAME I WOULD LIKE TO BE AS THE IMAGE ABOVE:

\begin{frame}[fragile]{}
The major current challenges are:
\clearpage
\begin{itemize}
      \tikzmark{t1}  \item[1.] Optimize the acquisition costs (time and money) of big data to create novel opportunities for academics (Sivarajah et al., 2017).
      
    \tikzmark{t2} \item[2.] Combine the significant advantages provided by the two disciplines of ML and econometrics (H. R. Varian, 2014).
\end{itemize}

\tikzmark{n1} 1. is addressed in the first part of the Dissertation; \\~\\
\tikzmark{n2} 2. is addressed in the second part of the Dissertation;

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        %\path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([yshift=3mm]n1) to ++(0,3mm) to [out=0, in=0,distance=2.5in] (t1);
   \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([yshift=3mm]n1) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My actual code does not display any arrow at all. Is there any package conflict? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here, some are not directly related to your question:

1. You should not load packages twice in your code (such as `tikz`) and keep your preamble sorted and clean. In the code below, I removed everything that has nothing to do with the actual question.
2. `\clearpage` should not be used at this place. Use `\bigskip` or something similar instead in order to insert vertical space.

Other problems are directly related to your question, namely:

3. You must not place anything *before* `\item`. This will always result in an error. You may place the `\tikzmark` inside the optional argument of `\item` that holds the label.
4. Marks that are defined using the `\tikzmark` macro can be referenced in a follwing `tikzpicture` environment with `pic cs:<name>`. Note the difference to `\tikzmarknode`.

A possible solution could be as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

%%%%%% HERE IS THE FRAME I WOULD LIKE TO BE AS THE IMAGE ABOVE:

\begin{frame}{}
The major current challenges are:
\bigskip

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\tikzmark{t1}1.] Optimize the acquisition costs (time and money) of big data to create novel opportunities for academics (Sivarajah et al., 2017).
    \item[\tikzmark{t2}2.] Combine the significant advantages provided by the two disciplines of ML and econometrics (H. R. Varian, 2014).
\end{itemize}

\tikzmark{n1}1. is addressed in the first part of the Dissertation; \\~\\
\tikzmark{n2}2. is addressed in the second part of the Dissertation;

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:t1) to[bend right] ([xshift=-2pt, yshift=1ex]pic cs:n1);
    \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<3-> ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:t2) to[bend right] ([xshift=-2pt, yshift=1ex]pic cs:n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While you're fixing stuff ... I'd use `enumerate` for *both* lists. Then maybe the `enumitem` package can be used to automate putting in the tikzmarks.

Comment: Good idea! Post another answer then =) I just thought by fixing I could explain best why things went wrong in the original code.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Don't use `enumitem` with `beamer`, that'll only create havoc!

Comment: @Skillmon there was a little nagging voice at the back of my head when I posted that saying that something wouldn't work, but I couldn't remember what it was. You're right.  With beamer, I guess one could set up a tikzmark template.

Answer (score 3):

*Thanks to [Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47927/jasper-habicht) for [its simplified MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625657/14500)*

Here is an automatic solution using `enumerate` and its optional argument (and via the `\automarkenumi` macro to add a tikzmark with the current value of `enumi`).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\def\automarkenumi#1{\tikzmark{#1\theenumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
The major current challenges are:
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}[\automarkenumi{t}1.]
    \item Optimize the acquisition costs (time and money) of big data to create novel opportunities for academics (Sivarajah et al., 2017).
    \item Combine the significant advantages provided by the two disciplines of ML and econometrics (H. R. Varian, 2014).
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[\automarkenumi{n}a.]
\item is addressed in the first part of the Dissertation;
\item is addressed in the second part of the Dissertation;
\end{enumerate}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<1-> ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:t1) to[bend right] ([xshift=-2pt, yshift=1ex]pic cs:na);
    \path[draw=magenta,thick,->]<1-> ([xshift=-2pt]pic cs:t2) to[bend right] ([xshift=-2pt, yshift=1ex]pic cs:nb);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys. While the code works perfectly, it also generates two additional slides identical to the one with arrow but without arrows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @NutarelliFederico This is probably because of the overlay secifications `<3->` that tells beamer to only show the arrows from the third sub-slide onwards. You may want to change them to `<2>` (just have one slide without and one with the arrows) or omit them altogether. Check the beamer manual for more information.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you. Now it works perfectly. Great work!